# Binding a value to input form select-element in Blazor only sets the value after making a selection

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I am using Blazor Server and trying to bind a value to the selected option in a HTML form.

My code is basically like this:

```
<select @bind="@formData.Cat">
<option>Cute cat</option>
<option>Bad cat</option>
<option>Hungry cat</option>
</select>
```

My formData is a class with this property:

```
public class FormData
{
    public string Cat { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine after I make a selection. But by default it's not being set to "Cute cat", even though it shows up default in the select box.
What's the easiest way to make it do that right away? The "value" attribute in HTML can't be used, it throws an error because the @bind is already using it.

I came up this:

```
public class FormData
{
    public string Cat { get; set; } = "Cute cat";
}
```

I don't think it's too elegant.

Any ideas?